# Listview is not sorting properly in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to sort a listview and then remove redundant items. But neither the items are sorted properly nor the redundancies are removed completely. Please help..

```
lvwMessages.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending; 

for (int i = 0; i < lvwMessages.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
   if (lvwMessages.Items[i].Tag == lvwMessages.Items[i + 1].Tag)
       lvwMessages.Items[i + 1].Remove();    
}
```

[image: Listview at runtime with unsorted and redundant items]

Comment: Take a look at this article and see if it helps, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the collection as you are iterating it. That always has some funny side-effects.

E.G. Let's say you have five items with ids and tags, respectively,

```
ID0 - Tag1 
ID1 - Tag1 
ID2 - Tag1
ID3 - Tag2
ID4 - Tag2.
```

First time through the loop, i = 0, and the Items collection has 5 elements.
ID0 is compared with ID1, and ID1 is removed.

Next time through the loop, i=1, and the Items collection has 4 elements.
Now, instead of comparing ID0 with ID2, ID2 is compared with ID3, and nothing is removed, etc...

You could use something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < lvwMessages.Items.Count - 1)
{
   if (lvwMessages.Items[i].Tag == lvwMessages.Items[i + 1].Tag)
      lvwMessages.Items[i + 1].Remove();    
   else
      i++;
}
```

incrementing the counter only if you have not removed an item.

Comment: You should use something like @lazyberezovsky's solution about sorting, and then use the code for removing.

Answer (score 0):

Property `Sorting` sorts items based on the item text. If you want to sort the items in the ListView based on `Tag`, you should use the Sort method. The Sort method uses the `IComparer` specified in the `ListViewItemSorter` property to perform a manual sort of the items in the ListView.

Here is an example of sorter:

```
public class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        YourType a = (YourType)((ListViewItem)x).Tag;
        YourType b = (YourType)((ListViewItem)y).Tag;
        // compare tags
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
listView.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer();
```

If you want to change sorting direction, multiply result by `-1` or use `b.Compare(a)`.